# Data Binding andGoogle Services plugin not work together

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I use firebase on my project. So at the bottom of my app/build.gradle file is

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

When I want to activate Databinding with

```
dataBinding {enabled true}
```

I'm getting the error;

> "Gradle sync failed: Can not change dependencies of configuration ': app: api' after it has been included in dependency resolution."

As a result, when multiple plugins are added, DataBinding gives an error. I still can not find a solution.
How to use data binding in a project using Google Services?

Android Studio 3.1.2
Gradle 4.4

---

The problem is in the gms version. The problem has been resolved with version 4.0.1

```
// classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'                   
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix with further steps -

1 In App level bulid.gradel file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.com.apptest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
} buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// add firbase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

 }
```

2. Project level gradel file.

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
 }
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```